# What is the number of unique permutations in a list with repeated elements, if they are also considered equal under a phase shift?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

This is similar to many questions asked before, but none seem to need to be unique under a phase shift as well.
Basically, my problem is, how many unique combinations in a group of 11 are there, if there need to be 5 A's and 6 B's.
For example [A,A,B,A,B,B,B,A,B,B,A]. However, they must also have to be unique when shifted. So for example, that set would be equivalent to [A,B,A,B,B,B,A,B,B,A,A].
I hope the explanation makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: What does "shifted" mean here? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: Wouldn't this be the same as a seated around a circular table arrangement? You can look up problems of that ilk.

Comment: So a shift would be to move the group one element to the left, and then to place the element from the start at the end, similar to the two groups in the question.

Comment: Quite possibly this question refers to Polya counting using the cycle indices of the cyclic / dihedral group (necklaces and bracelets). The simplest case is when the number of slots is prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you place these $A$'s and $B$'s in a line of length $11$. From $11$ choose $5$ places for the $A$'s, and from the remaining $11-5=6$ choose $6$ places for the $B$'s. Because a given arrangement can be shifted over $11$ times and still be counted as just one arrangement, we divide the total number by $11$. Therefore we get $$\frac {\binom {11}{5} \binom {6}{6}}{11}=42$$
In the general case, with $n$ $A$'s and $m$ $B$'s, we have, by the same logic $$\frac {\binom {n+m}{n} \binom {n+m-n}{m}}{n+m}$$

Comment: I think that might be just what I need, thank you. One quick question, would this be a more difficult calculation to make if the length was not a prime number, and instead was 10 or 8, as there are more symmetries within the combinations?

Comment: @Luke I added some details.

Comment: Ah thank you that is great. Sorry to keep asking questions, but, so if i were to have 4 A's and 4 B's, unless I've calculated it wrong, it seems to come out as 8.75 combinations, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This formula is correct only when $n+m$ is a prime number and $n, m \ne 0$, because in that case an arrangement and its shifted iterates form a set of $n+m$ different arrangements. When $n+m$ is not prime, it is not always the case. By the way $\binom{n+m-n}{m} = 1$

Comment: @Luke for those more complicated cases, you need to consider when are arrangements overcounted $10$ times and when they are overcounted less than $10$ times. This can be done using Burnside's lemma, which says that given a number of patterns, you can find those distinguishable up to motions (in this case rotations) by finding the average that are fixed by one of these motions.